# How to split lines in a file into groups?

Tags: scala

I am trying to find a way to read and split large log files into events in a functional way. I have an imperative way (e.g., uses mutable states, no composable). I looked at [Best way to read lines in groups in a flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171078/best-way-to-read-lines-in-groups-in-a-flat-file) -- unfortunately, my file does not have a defined delimiter like END. Also that solution consumes the END line.

My file looks something like this

```
Nov 28, 2015 2:30:47 PM CST Info Security BEA-090905 Disabling CryptoJ JC ...
Nov 28, 2015 2:30:47 PM CST Info Security BEA-090906 Changing the default .....
2015-11-28 14:33:08,320:ERROR:[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': [1448742788318]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Errors>
        <Error ErrorCode="INVERR01"
            ErrorDescription="SKU information missing" ErrorUniqueExceptionId="10.7.44.4914487427882870000000000001">
        <Attrib  
    ...
```

Some events are one line, some are stack traces, etc. In the example above, I would like to get 3 events. I have working imperative code

```
var wip = false
var uow = ""
var sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder
Source.
  fromFile(f).
  getLines.
  toStream.
  zipWithIndex.
  foreach {
    case (l, index) => {
      l match {
        case ln if ln.trim == "" =>

        case ln if ue.isBeginLine(ln) && wip => 
          processEvent(sb.toString, ue)
          sb.setLength(0) 
          sb.append(ln)

        case ln if ue.isBeginLine(ln) && !wip => 
          wip = true
          sb.append("\n").append(ln)

        case ln if wip => sb.append("\n").append(ln)

        case ln        => log.info(">> Worker:  Rejecting: %s".format(ln))
      } // match
  }} // foreach
```

I can identify the start of events using the following method **ue.isBeginLine**. The following is sample code (customized for each different log format) -- I will make the isBeginLine more generic later.

```
def isBeginLine(s: String): Boolean =
      s.startsWith("2015") |
      s.startsWith("<Nov 28") |
      s.startsWith("WebLogic") |
      s.startsWith("INFO:") |
      s.startsWith("WARNING:") |
      s.startsWith("Parsing") |
      s.startsWith("Nov 28")
```

As mentioned above, I tried the following (from [Best way to read lines in groups in a flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171078/best-way-to-read-lines-in-groups-in-a-flat-file)). Unfortunately, the approach below requires a defined terminator or delimiter for each event

```
val i = Source.
    fromFile(f).
    getLines

def groupIterator(xs: Iterator[String]) = new Iterator[String] { 
    var tmp = new StringBuffer
    def hasNext = xs.hasNext 
    def next = xs.takeWhile(!_.startsWith("2015")).mkString("\n") 
}

for (g <- groupIterator(i)) println("=======\n" + g + "\n==========")
```

So out of curiosity, is there a better, functional way to parse log files into events? Ideally, I would like something like the following to aggregate the events.

```
Source.
  fromFile(f).
  getLines.
  """splitEvents""".   
  foldLeft( HashMap[String, Event]() )( .... ) )
```

Comment: if you can define a grammar for your events then a parser combinator library like fastparse (https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse) can help you interpret each line.

Comment: Eduardo -- thanks. I will take a look at the parser approach.  Although I am currently shying away from a parser because (and I could be wrong) I need the approach to be easily extensible by junior employees when they discover an event with a new format.

Comment: Paser combinators (fastparse in particular) tend to be easy to learn and use, and to extend, (at least easier than lex/yacc, or handwriting the rules yourself).

Comment: @Bernie - fastparse is ridiculously easy to use compared to manually parsing stuff.  If junior employees can't learn to handle that, there's no way they're going to reliably get manual parsing right.  The reason not to use fastparse is that it's a bit slower than a careful manual approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same kind of approach, but use `BufferedIterator` so you have access to `head` as a lookahead.  It's a little less functional but you can wrap it yourself to make it act functional again on the outside.  The core routine could look something like

```
def getNextChunk(i: BufferedIterator[String]): Option[Array[String]] =
  if (!i.hasNext) None
  else {
    var ab = Array.newBuilder[String]
    ab += i.next
    while (i.hasNext && !isRecordStart(i.head)) ab += i.next
    Some(ab.result)
  }
```

and then you just call that over and over until you hit a `None`.  You could, for instance,

```
Iterator.continually(getNextChunk(i)).
  takeWhile(_.isDefined).
  map(_.get)
```

to get an iterator of chunks.

Or you could make your own `GroupedIterator` off of a `BufferedIterator` that implements the same thing; it'll probably be a bit more efficient that way.